# display unicode and non unicode in div using inline css

Tags: php, html, css, unicode

My php script may generate unicode or non unicode. How do i display both types of data inside div that uses inline css?

All the datas are generated by php like:
$content = "May be unicode or non:".$data."";

Is there a way to use inline "font-family" with multiple fonts?

Comment: Your not very clear. What do you mean with non unicode? And why do you end your posting in a question about multiple fonts, what has this to do with php?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are three distinct topics in the “question” that do not have much in common.

**1.)** Using **Unicode** is something you should do everywhere. Since you can't mix different encodings in a single (HTML-) document, you are definitely either only use Unicode or something else. You can't mix it. And it is your choice and decision in which encoding to render or save the HTML document.

**2.)** **PHP** is able to print Unicode characters without any trouble. Make sure you are sending the correct encoding HTTP headers to the client as well.

And **3.)** **CSS** renders text based on a per-character stream. You can define multiple fonts as fallback fonts in CSS, e.g. `font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;` and if one character is not found in the first specified font, CSS will use the next font and try to render the given character with that font. This way you can mix several fonts, based on the code-points and availability of each character in each font.

Nonetheless this is still Unicode. Don't confuse fonts and encoding.